# wxPython segfaults on locale.Init()

Tags: segmentation-fault, wxpython, locale

I have this code in wxPython:

```
locale = wx.Locale()
locale.AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix('./locale')
locale.Init(wx.LANGUAGE_DUTCH)
locale.AddCatalog('lembox')
```

However, when running this in Cinnamon under Arch, it segfaults at the `Init` line regardless of the language with the message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I am running Arch 4.3.3-2 on x64_64.

**Edit:** The main file looks like this:

```
import wx

import main_app

app = wx.App()


def main():
    app = wx.App(False)

    locale = wx.Locale()
    locale.AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix('./locale')
    locale.Init(wx.LANGUAGE_DUTCH)
    locale.AddCatalog('lembox')

    main_app.TaskBarIcon()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The app doesn't segfault if I don't call locale.Init().

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Where are those four lines in your program? Are they in a class?

Comment: I have added the entire code for my entry point file.

Comment: After some extended research, I am going to try rebuilding wxPython for my machine.

Comment: Probably a good idea. I just ran your code with no issues.